# KQL : how to get memory increments above certain threshold?

Tags: kql

The following KQL query gives me the logs regarding memory usage for an app

```
traces
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| where message startswith_cs "memory_profiler_logs:"
| parse message with "memory_profiler_logs: " LineNumber "  " TotalMem_MiB "  " IncreMem_MiB "  " Occurrences "  " Contents
| union (
    traces
    | where timestamp > ago(1d)
    | where message startswith_cs "memory_profiler_logs: Filename: "
    | where 
    | parse message with "memory_profiler_logs: Filename: " FileName
    | project timestamp, FileName, itemId
)
| project timestamp, LineNumber=iff(FileName != "", FileName, LineNumber), TotalMem_MiB, IncreMem_MiB, Occurrences, Contents, RequestId=itemId
| order by timestamp asc
```

how can I modify the query in order to get only records with IncreMem_MiB > 1000MiB ?

I tried adding the following with no success:

```
| where IncreMem_MiB > 1000
```

Comment: To filter records in a Kusto Query Language (KQL) query where `IncreMem_MiB` is greater than 1000, add the `where IncreMem_MiB > 1000` clause after defining the `IncreMem_MiB` field but before ordering the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
traces
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| where message startswith_cs "memory_profiler_logs:"
| parse message with "memory_profiler_logs: " LineNumber "  " TotalMem_MiB "  " IncreMem_MiB "  " Occurrences "  " Contents
| where IncreMem_MiB > 1000
| union (
    traces
    | where timestamp > ago(1d)
    | where message startswith_cs "memory_profiler_logs: Filename: "
    | where 
    | parse message with "memory_profiler_logs: Filename: " FileName
    | project timestamp, FileName, itemId
)
| project timestamp, LineNumber=iff(FileName != "", FileName, LineNumber), TotalMem_MiB, IncreMem_MiB, Occurrences, Contents, RequestId=itemId
| order by timestamp asc
```

The where clause is after the parse operator and filters the results based on IncreMem_MiB